# gdb record restore not working as expected

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb, g++

I have this simple C++ program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout << "Hello" << endl; 
 return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't segfault.

I run gdb like so:

```
gdb a.out
break main
run
target record
record save
s
record stop
c
quit
```

Then I call gdb again:

```
gdb
record restore gdb_record.21158
[New LWP 21158]
Core was generated by `a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 5, Trace/breakpoint trap.
\#0  0x08048617 in ?? ()
Segmentation fault
```

Update more info

```
(gdb) record save
warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 4096 bytes at 0xffffffffff600000.
Saved core file gdb_record.6490 with execution log.
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
Hello
__libc_start_main (main=0x5555555551a9 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe108, 
    init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
    stack_end=0x7fffffffe0f8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:342
342 ../csu/libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably issue was that you didn't start gdb with a.out. So it should be

```
gdb a.out
record restore gdb_record.21158
record goto end
```

Comment: I tried with gdb a.out and I get the same problem. I've added some more information for when I save the record and when I step in it. I saw this "Memory read failed for corefile section" and "../csu/libc-start.c: No such file or directory.".